# Hello I am stuck at integrating Stripe to the Next js

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, next.js13

I want to build a custom checkout page and use a built-in API in Next.js. What tool should I use for forms, or are there any templates that have validations, etc., in Stripe? What should I do with them? What documentation should I read? Please answer.

I tried learning Stripe.js, but it's more focused on how to set it up with a Node server.

Comment: Does [this](https://vercel.com/guides/getting-started-with-nextjs-typescript-stripe) answer your question? It was the first thing that has plopped up when I googled for "nextjs and stripe", please do some research before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't help with the Next.js portion of your question since Stripe doesn't have an official Next.js integration, but you should still be able to use Stripe.js in whatever js framework. So, if you want a custom checkout page, you can use [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements).